# UITableView Empty in iOS 7

Tags: ios, uitableview, is-empty

I recently updated to Xcode 5 and when i run my application the UITableView appears to be empty:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
     - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     {
           static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Notes";
           UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
           id obj = [matchedObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            if ([obj isKindOfClass:[Notes class]]) {
                     Notes *note = obj;
                     cell.textLabel.text = note.topic;
                     cell.detailTextLabel.text = note.subject;
                     cell.imageView.image = nil;
             }
             else
             {
                      Picture *picture = obj;
                      UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:picture.image];
                      cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Image", nil);
                      cell.imageView.image = image;
                      cell.detailTextLabel.text = picture.subject;
             }
             NSLog(@"Cell Text %@",cell.textLabel.text);

             return cell;
       }
```

I already implemented:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 10;
}
```

The white space above appears to be the cells. I think it has something to do with iOS 7. This is worked in xcode 4.5 . Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Have you set the `delegate` and `datasource` to the `viewController`? and what's with that white space on the top?

Comment: @KyleFang Yes I did and the white space appears to be the cell. I think it has something to do with ios 7 it worked in xcode 4.5

Comment: 4.5? I'm guessing that your cell is a default style cell, in that case, check the font color? (Just in case)....

Comment: @KyleFang In the storyboard the label is black...

Comment: @KyleFang Have any idea why the cells are like that?

Comment: It's a system style cell or a custom cell?

Comment: Try set the background, maybe the text is empty?

Comment: @KyleFang It is a subtitle cell

Comment: @KyleFang The text is not empty I NSLogged it.

Comment: Did the background shown up? Try set it to red or something

Comment: @KyleFang That is weird. It stays white

Comment: Is it possible that something else is on the screen, other views maybe.... And check of a tableViewHeaderView

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37791/discussion-between-kyle-fang-and-abdullah-shafique)

Comment: @KyleFang I fixed the bug!!!

Comment: There is another view on top. Put it as an answer so I can give you a check...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a view covering my UITableView. Thanks for everyone that helped!

Comment: @kirtimali I removed the view from the UITableView.

Comment: meanas removed view from footer and header in table-view right ?

Comment: @kirtimali I had a view on my tableview. I called `[view2 removeFromSuperView];`

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to implement tableview other 2 important delegates:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 10;
}
```

Comment: cellForRowAtIndexPath get called? or not ?

Comment: It is getting called.

Comment: Did you set CellIdentifier to Notes in your storyboard?

Comment: Did you connect the cell's IBOutlets ?

Comment: ahh ok, i m trying to figure out what could be your problem

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue on a table showing different product IDs to be purchased.
Same issue in the iOS simulator but everything works well on the actual device.
Have you tested on your iPhone/iPad, also?

Comment: I found the solution already. A view was blocking the UITableView.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced same issue [UILabel in UITable do not get display but get display on click in IOS 7 (due to issue with background colour)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186689/uilabel-in-uitable-do-not-get-display-but-get-display-on-click-in-ios-7-due-to/20189385#20189385)
and i found that

1. The issue was with the default background colour of the cell.
2. In Ios 6 and 5 it use to set black but in Ios 7 it is set to White.

So the solution is:
[cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]]; 
or set Text colour other than white if you choose to keep your background colour white.

Answer (score 1):

My Issue was :

My tableview's height was 0. Not sure y.

(I had my tableview in XIB)

But, I fixed it by manually setting it to some static size.